# Adding any value to maximum integer value is giving wrong calculation

Tags: java, integer, type-conversion, short

I am adding two number 2147483647 and 45

```
public void checkIntAdd(){

int intMax =  2147483647;
int anyNumber  = 26;

int number = intMax+anyNumber;
System.out.println("Wrong Calculation -"+number);

}
```

Answer should we

> "2147483692

" but it is coming as

> -2147483604

that i am fine with it that it is loosing some value

but when i tried this type of thing with short it is giving compilation error as

```
public void checkShortAdd(){

short intMax =  214;
short anyNumber  = 26;

short number = intMax+anyNumber;  // error is coming Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to short
System.out.println("Wrong Calculation -"+number);

}
```

> // error is coming Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to short

i am not able to understand the cause for it .

when i add cast to it work fine

```
short number = (short) (intMax+anyNumber);
```

Similarly int addition should be given error by compiler so that user can take care that it will go out of bound as in case of short

Comment: The result you are getting is not `2147483604`. It is `-2147483604`.

Comment: Adding two shorts can eventually be an int that cannot be fit into a short.

Comment: ***Answer should we 2147483692***..... how?

Comment: Try casting the short to an int before the addition. Put parenthesis around the cast to make sure it happens first. Seems like the compiler wants to convert the int to a short before the math happens but the int is too large to be downgraded to a short.

Comment: @Jaroslaw Pawlak corrected it

Comment: @SarthAk you have also changed another number which you shouldn't have changed. Anyway, now that you know that adding two positive numbers gives you a negative result, read about integer overflow in Java.

Comment: i am asking simple only that compiler is complaining about short addition but not about int addition

Comment: is there any design issue related to it

Comment: By the way, the `…Exact` methods on [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html) throw exception upon overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number 1: the first number is the maximum integer size in Java. You can get this with

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

You can use

```
 BigInteger reallyBig = new BigInteger("1234567890123456890");
```

Number 2: In Java, it lies in the basic coding of the language. Simplified, you can say short + short = int, so you have to cast it for the correct solution

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/3refus/in_java_why_is_the_sum_of_2_shorts_an_int/

Answer (score 1):

TL, DR...

this is valid `short intMax = 214;` because even thou 214 is an int literal, it fits in the bounds of a short..., same for `short anyNumber = 26;`
 now java compiler can not warrant that this

```
short number =  intMax + anyNumber;
```

still can fit a short variable, so you need to cast

```
short number = (short) (intMax + anyNumber);
```

Comment: same thing i could say about int also there no typecasting is required

Comment: in my example i have added two shorts only and assign it to a short only

Answer (score 0):

According to java language specifications

Most of the instructions in the Java Virtual Machine instruction set encode type information about the operations they perform. For instance, the iload instruction (§iload) loads the contents of a local variable, which must be an int, onto the operand stack. The fload instruction (§fload) does the same with a float value. The two instructions may have identical implementations, but have distinct opcodes.

[image: opcode table for java]

in this table there are no operation ment for short byte char.

The mapping between Java Virtual Machine actual types and Java Virtual Machine computational types as

[image: Mapping between Java Virtual Machine actual types and Java Virtual Machine computational types]

in which it says that short default type is int only

so i just want to look deep into my program so i just run a command as

```
javap -verbose RunTimeS.class
```

and out put contains

> iload_1

that integer is loading

[image: Verbose output for class]